# Symfony4 translation in twig

Tags: php, symfony, twig, translation, symfony4

As for Symfony4 translation, thanks to this [article](https://symfony.com/doc/current/translation.html#twig-templates). It works well in Controller.

```
 public function index(TranslatorInterface $translator)
    {
        $translated = $translator->trans('test');// it works
        print $translated;exit;
```

in messages.en.yaml

```
test: englishtest
```

However I can't translate message in twig.

```
<br>
{{ test|trans }}
<br>
```

It shows the error `Variable "test" does not exist.`

I need to do something in advance for translation in twig???

Comment: <br>
{{ 'test'|trans }}
<br>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method signature looks like this:

```
{{ message|trans(arguments = [], domain = null, locale = null) }}
```

See https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/twig_reference.html#trans

So if `test` is not a variable, then `{{ 'test'|trans }}` should work (as zalex already pointed out).